# How can I match these strings with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file that looks like this

```
0001 fd
0002 gfgd
0003 hgjhgj
0004 hfhfdgd
0005 nfgnghfgh
0006 hfhfg
0007 fgdgdfhf vn
```

I need to extract the last two lines which are `0006` and `0007`.

How can I do this using regex for python?

Note: In the txt file, the numbers  are random and repeating at different parts of the file. Meaning there can be multiple 0006's.

Comment: Can you add to your question what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
import re
filetext = open('file.txt')
for line in filetext:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('0006|0007', line):
        print(line)
```

**It will give you result like this:**

```
0006 hfhfg
0007 fgdgdfhf vn
```

Hope this will help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the last two line you can use `readlines()` and `list slicing`.

**Ex:**

```
import re
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    data  = infile.readlines()[-2:]
print(re.findall("\d+", " ".join(data)))
```

**Output:**

```
['0006', '0007']
```

Comment: The lines I need aren't only the last two lines.
has a lot of lines and I need to extract the the lines that has the letters 'vn' in them and the line above it.

Comment: Can you post an example please?

Comment: http://collabedit.com/y2m3g

Here's an example. The strings I need to extract are the ones with "vn" and the line above it. I tried different regex patterns alreadt. They work on line like on regex101 but once I run on Python 2.7 it gives out no match.